# How to use common density function and central limit theorem to compute P(S > 70)?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Say I have a common density function as the following:

$f(x) =  \begin{cases}
       {2(1-x),} &{0 < x < 1}\\
       {0} &{otherwise}\\
     \end{cases} $

Let's say $S = X_1 + ... + X_{200}$. I want to find $P(S>70)$. Now this is what I thought on how to solve it, I figured that the 'easiest' way to solve this is by using the central limit theorem. But how to find $P(S>70)$ exactly using the central limit theorem wasn't straightforward. My intuition right away was to compute the mean and the variance of $X_1,...,X_{200}$ (note these values are independent continuous random variables)because I thought it will be needed to solve $P(S>70)$, however I am quite unsure on how to tackle this one after computing those values, also kind of unsure if I am on the right track in general. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, a first step is find the mean and variance of the $X_i$. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I did it taking the derivative of $2(1-x)$ from 0 to 1. Basically used it to find $E(x)$, then used $E(x)$ into $Var(x) = E[(X-u)^{2}]$ to compute the variance.

Comment: For the mean, you need $\int_0^1 (x)(2)(1-x)\,dx$. I think this turns out to be $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yeah, that's how I computed it, and what I got.

Comment: Did you find that the variance is $\frac{1}{18}$?  For the variance, it is easier to use $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  Yeah I got that variance as well. Ah yeah it was easier that way to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will need to assume the $X_i$ are independent.

First we compute the mean and variance of the $X_i$. We have
$$E(X_i)=\int_0^1 (x)(2)(1-x)\,dx=\frac{1}{3}.$$
Also
$$E(X_i^2)=\int_0^1 (x^2)(2)(1-x)\,dx=\frac{1}{6},$$
and therefore $\text{Var}(X_i)=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{18}$.

Thus $S$ has mean $\frac{200}{3}$. The variance of $S$ is $\frac{200}{18}$. This is because the variance of a sum of *independent* random variables is the sum of the variances. So the standard deviation of $S$ is $\frac{10}{3}$.

Informally, $S$ has a reasonably close to normal distribution, because it is the sum of a fairly large number of independent identically distributed random variables with a "nice enough" distribution.

So our probability is approximately the probability that a *normal* with mean $\frac{200}{3}$ and standard deviation $\frac{10}{3}$ is greater than $70$. Some software will let you find this probability directly.

A more old-fashioned (but still useful) approach is to note that we want
$$\Pr\left(Z\gt \frac{70-\frac{200}{3}}{\frac{10}{3}}\right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. Now you can use a table of the standard normal, or software, to finish. We end up wanting $\Pr(Z\gt 1)$.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now. Using software I checked my solution, the final answer I got was 0.07259122, I used R, to double check incase I made a mistake, is this right?

Comment: From tables, $\Pr(Z\gt 1)\approx 0.1587$.

Comment: I made a mistake with the function call, but looking at the tables I found 0.1587.